# How can I get an OR in my Where clause?

Tags: linq-to-sql, where-clause, adhoc

I'm building an ad-hoc query to send to SQL doing the following:

```
var data = from d in db.xxxx select d;
foreach (pattern in user_stuff)
   data = data.Where(d=>SqlMethods.Like(d.item,pattern)==true);
```

The problem is that the `WHERE` clauses get `AND`'ed together. I need `OR`'s.

Any idea how to get an `OR`?

Answer (score 3):

How about I answer my own question:
[PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: PerpetualCoder, you can't || together a dynamic list of predicates. That's why you need a predicate builder.

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct an Expression to represent the composite OR predicate, then pass that to Where:

```
var data = from d in db.xxxx select d;
Expression<Func<Data, bool>> predicate = null;
foreach (var pattern in user_stuff)
{
    Expression<Func<Data, bool>> newPredicate = d => SqlMethods.Like(d..item, pattern));
    if (predicate == null) predicate = newPredicate;
    else predicate = Expression.OrElse(predicate, newPredicate);
}
return data.Where(predicate);
```

---

EDIT: This is probably what PredicateBuilder does, only a lot messier :)